# Android: Simple way to upload a picture to an image host

Tags: android, upload

I d like to upload a picture to a host like: http://imagerz.com/ .
Any sample for this? I can do a simple POST request, but how I can add the image content to my POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tutorial that tells you how to send a file **via FTP** to a server. [File upload and download using Java](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/36-file-upload-and-download-using-java.html)

It shouldn't be very hard to "port" that code into android. (You may have to change some of the classes/methods as some of them may not be implemented in Android's lightweight VM).

There are also other image hosting services that should have an api that you could follow.

**EDIT:**

As you stated, you wanted to do this with a post request.

I found this great tutorial with the following code:

```
package com.commonsbook.chap9;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.MultipartPostMethod;

public class HttpMultiPartFileUpload {
    private static String url =
      "http://localhost:8080/HttpServerSideApp/ProcessFileUpload.jsp";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        MultipartPostMethod mPost = new MultipartPostMethod(url);
        client.setConnectionTimeout(8000);

        // Send any XML file as the body of the POST request
        File f1 = new File("students.xml");
        File f2 = new File("academy.xml");
        File f3 = new File("academyRules.xml");

        System.out.println("File1 Length = " + f1.length());
        System.out.println("File2 Length = " + f2.length());
        System.out.println("File3 Length = " + f3.length());

        mPost.addParameter(f1.getName(), f1);
        mPost.addParameter(f2.getName(), f2);
        mPost.addParameter(f3.getName(), f3);

        int statusCode1 = client.executeMethod(mPost);

        System.out.println("statusLine>>>" + mPost.getStatusLine());
        mPost.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload

The same issues about porting this code to android as I stated above apply.