# upload image from android to php server

Tags: php, android, upload, image

I'm trying to upload a photo from android device to a php website.
For this I'm using `MultipartEntity` encoding.

For this I `added` to my project as an `external jar file` `httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar`.

What I want to upload to the php website is a `image` stored on the `SDcard`.
To this end I'm doing the following in my code:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("....the link to the webiste...");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        StringBody sb=new StringBody("....");


        File file=new File("/sdcard/image.jpg");
        FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);
        reqEntity.addPart("android",bin);
        reqEntity.addPart("id", sb);

        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();


       if (resEntity != null) {
            String page = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            System.out.println("PAGE :" + page);
        }
```

But the problem with this is that the response from php server is always a broken link.

What I wanna try next is to use

```
 MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

But unfortunately the `jar` I imported doesn't has the class for `HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE`.So I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction-what else should I import for this to work....or how should I upload the image to the server.
I must say that the server is build to upload photo this way:

```
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                      name="form" target="_self" id="form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="p" value="a" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably looking for something like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476625/android-simple-way-to-upload-a-picture-to-an-image-host/5476726#5476726

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not to use a `beta` library. You should use [apache-mime4j-0.6](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/james/apache-mime4j/0.6/apache-mime4j-0.6-sources.jar) .

You will also need [httpmime-4.0.1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.0.1/httpmime-4.0.1.jar).

These need to be your imports:

```
      import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
      import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
      import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
      import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
      import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
      import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
      import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
      import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
      import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
      import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
      import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
      import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

Comment: Now it tells me:The type org.apache.james.mime4j.message.SingleBody cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
 files at this lines: MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();reqEntity.addPart("android",bin);
     reqEntity.addPart("id", sb);

Comment: Am importat deja librariile alea, am adaugat zeci de jar uri si tot imi da eroare la linia respectiva!

Comment: import that class too then import org.apache.james.mime4j.message.SingleBody;

Comment: Crezi ca o recunoaste?Nu exista clasa respectiva in librarii!:)

Comment: @george let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1942/discussion-between-ovidiu-latcu-and-george)

Comment: I inported httpmime-4.0-beta1.jar instead but I still can't use that class:MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);